Dynamically including PrismaORM relations with type safety
I come from a background full of Java backends. Now I'm working on a project using ExpressJS with Typescript as the backend. The ORM we use is Prisma.
  async findById(id: string, relations: string[] = []) {
    const includedRelations = relations.reduce((acc: Record<string, boolean>, curr: string) => {
      acc[curr] = true;
      return acc;
    }, {});

    return prisma.contract.findUnique({
      where: {
        id
      },
      include: includedRelations
    });
  }

This method is supposed to retrieve Contracts including specified relations. The problem is that when I use that function the type that gets returned is only the generated Contract type without the relations. I know that I could probably fix the issue if I would remove the relations parameter so that those don't change, but that's exactly what I want this function to do. I want to call it to retrieve a Contract with some or without including relations. How could I implement that here?
type ContractWithRelations = Prisma.PromiseReturnType<typeof findById>

I have already tried to use this type to fix the problem, but it just assumes the plain Contract type, because it can't figure out which relations are included in the returned value.

There are some informations about relations you can use as references.
https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-schema/data-model/relations
Base on your case, you actually can check your data first if want to show data without relations. For example
async findById(id: string, relations: string[] = []) {
  if (relations.length === 0) {
    return prisma.contract.findUnique({
      where: {
        id
      }
    });
  }

  const includedRelations = relations.reduce((acc: Record<string, boolean>, curr: string) => {
    acc[curr] = true;
    return acc;
  }, {});

  return prisma.contract.findUnique({
    where: {
      id
    },
    include: includedRelations
  });
}

Happy to code :)
